# Can I replace a Lenovo Thinkpad's DVD drive with a SATA hard drive?

Tags: sata, dvd, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W510.
Currently I have a SSD 125GB hard drive in it, but that is too small for me.

Is it possible to replace my DVD drive with another SATA Hard Drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace your W510's optical drive with Lenovo's [ThinkPad Serial ATA Hard Drive Bay Adapter III](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=38&Code=43N3412&current-category-id=2478535BAB3C417CA9D77F5867D31462&&hide_menu_area=yes) (Part # 43N3412) and a larger SATA hard drive.

Comment: I replaced my optical drive with a SSD drive, using this method. It increased my battery life on the system by about 20%.   The lower wattage of the SSD (less than 1w) helped a lot.  The CDRom I think was a 5w power draw.

Answer (score 0):

Also check these places:

[http://www.amazon.com/drive-Caddy-IBM-Lenovo-Thinkpad/dp/B006U6US1E/ref=sr_1_1?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1340197939&sr=1-1&keywords=lenovo+hdd+bay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006U6US1E)

http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_7&products_id=392

http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=460&Code=43N3412&category-id=FDCD14101F7E452CBBA91660EB85C922&hide_menu_area=yes#learnMore